# Angular select doesn't respond to ng-model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I have a select that looks like this:

```
{{vm.selected}}
{{vm.items}}
<select ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in vm.items track by item.value" ng-model="vm.selected">
</select>
```

My items array looks like this:

```
this.items = [  
  {  
     "label":"Foo Bar",
     "value":"foobar"
  },
  {  
     "label":"Baz Quux",
     "value":"quux"
  }
];
```

and the item `vm.selected` is "foobar"

both bindings are displayed correctly above the select but the item is not selected. When I inspect the select in developer tools I have this as the first selected item:

```
<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>
```

Also when I am using click on this element with `ng-click="vm.selected = 'quux'"` nothing is changed. The `{{vm.selected}}` is always updated. Anybody have a clue what's wrong?

Comment: This should work correctly. Can you reproduce in a jsfiddle?

Comment: Instead of ng-click="vm.selected = 'quux'" , why dont you try :

ng-init = "vm.selected = items[2]'"

Comment: Bind directly to the object in the collection: [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#complex-models-objects-or-collections-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `track by item.value` is problematic.  If you remove that, you can see that after you select a value, `vm.selected` will present itself properly and the select works.

http://codepen.io/jusopi/pen/PbeoWN

Answer (score 1):

Your ng-option expression will not work according to [official ngOption documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Quoting

> but this will not work:
>
> `item.subItem as item.label for item in items track by item.id`

So your

> `ng-options="item.value as item.label for item in vm.items track by item.value"`

won't work.

Instead make yore expression of the following format:

> `item as item.label for item in items track by item.id`